# Excel VBA Dictionary duplicate key

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, hashmap

I have this code:

```
Dim list As Object
Set list = jsonParse.Item("list")

Dim groupedByProjectElement As New Dictionary
For i = 1 To 2
        Set pE = list(i).Item("projectElement")
        Dim projectElementsDictionary As New Dictionary
        If groupedByProjectElement.Exists(pE.Item("businessKey")) Then
            Set projectElementsDictionary = groupedByProjectElement(pE.Item("businessKey"))
            projectElementsDictionary.Add projectElementsDictionary.count + 1, list(i)
        End If
        If Not groupedByProjectElement.Exists(pE.Item("businessKey")) Then
            projectElementsDictionary.Add 1, list(i)
            groupedByProjectElement.Add pE.Item("businessKey"), projectElementsDictionary
        End If
Next i
```

In the second iteration I am getting the error:

```
This key is already associated with an element of this collection
```

But I am expecting that in the second iteration **projectElementsDictionary** should be a new Dictionary already.

What am I missing?

list looks something like this:

```
"list": [
    {
        "projectElement": {
            "businessKey": "123",
            "customerUnit": {
                "businessKey": "123",
                "links": [],
                "shortDescription": "123",
                "text": "123",
                "version": null
            }
        }  
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question:

```
Dim groupedByProjectElement As New Dictionary
For i = 1 To 25
    Set pE = List(i).Item("projectElement")
    Dim projectElementsDictionary As Dictionary
    If groupedByProjectElement.Exists(pE.Item("businessKey")) Then
        Set projectElementsDictionary = groupedByProjectElement(pE.Item("businessKey"))
        projectElementsDictionary.Add projectElementsDictionary.Count + 1, List(i)
    Else
        Set projectElementsDictionary = New Dictionary
        projectElementsDictionary.Add 1, List(i)
        groupedByProjectElement.Add pE.Item("businessKey"), projectElementsDictionary
    End If
Next i
```